# multiple dict value in safe_substitution function

Tags: python, dictionary

Need some insight on using the dictionary values in the safe_substitution function.
assume that i have 2 dict

```
import string

dict1={"a":" $b text1" ,"b":"$c text2"}
dict2={"c": "$d text3", "d" : "text4"}

finnal_text = string.template("$a").safe_substitute(dict1)
```

finnal_text = string.template("$a").safe_substitute(dict1,dict2)

if i try to use two dict variable it errors out... is there a way to use the 2 dict values in single safe_substitute func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict3 = dict(dict1)
dict3.update(dict2)
finnal_text = string.template("$a").safe_substitute(dict3)
```

however if both dicts have the same key the key from dict2 will be used or

```
finnal_text = string.template("$a").safe_substitute( dict(dict1.items()+dict2.items()) )
```

you could abstract this out to a function

```
def dict_merge(*dicts):
    return dict(item for d in dicts for item in d.items())

finnal_text = string.template("$a").safe_substitute( dict_merge(dict1,dict2) )
```